# Substring in appinsight

Tags: azure-application-insights, ms-app-analytics

How can I find a Substring in Microsoft AppInsight Analytics?

I have event with this template name:
"FinalStep-Start: 12:11:20.467 | End: 12:11:20.936"
I want to separate those two time, and after that compare them with each other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can parse the start and end times into their own columns using the "parse" operator:

```
| parse eventText with * "FinalStep-Start: " start " | End: " end
```

But because the [datetimes are not in a standard supported by analytics](https://docs.loganalytics.io/docs/Language-Reference/Data-types/datetime) I wasn't able to cast them into DateTime for further processing:

```
range x from 1 to 1 step 1
| extend eventText = "FinalStep-Start: 12:11:20.467 | End: 12:11:20.936"
| parse eventText with * "FinalStep-Start: " start " | End: " end
| extend start_dt = todatetime(start) 
| extend end_dt = todatetime(end)
```